# Do moderators have privileges to accept answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, moderators

Do moderators have the privilege to accept the answer on their own if answer gets much positive points and is helpful for users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Only the question's author can accept an answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks for answer! :)

Comment: But especially unregistered users tend to not accept an answer, and they will wander around like a ghost in the system :( Community (-1 user) will push them to first page every now and then, users look at the question again and again, but the answer has already been given. Would be nice if a moderator could accept an answer after like 2-3 months, or community vote after this time.

Comment: @CoDEmanX, as long as at least one answer is upvoted, Community will not bump the question.  The criteria for bumping is that both must be true: A) no upvoted answer, B) answer not accepted.